# PHPUnit: Mockery not found when using @runTestsInSeparateProcesses

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, mockery

I'm using PHPUnit with Mockery, the latter i installed via composer:

```
"require-dev": {
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*"
},
```

Now, consider the following test case

```
<?php

use Mockery as m;

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    function testFoo() {
        m::mock('DateTime');
    }
}
```

`phpunit` run fine. Now consider the following:

```
use Mockery as m;

/**
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    function testFoo() {
        m::mock('DateTime');
    }
}
```

In this case i get a  `Class 'Mockery' not found` exception.

`Mockery` is not found - actually, nothing in the `/vendor`  directory is found, as if the composer autoloading is totally messed up. I've ran both `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`.

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Package Test Suite">
            <directory suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>

    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

I'm using PHPUnit 3.7.10 and i run tests with command line `phpunit` without any args.

How can i fix this?

Comment: What is your exact command line? What is in your phpunit.xml? Where is PHPUnit installed? What is in the bootstrap script if there is one?

Comment: Hey @Sven, see edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to PHPUnit 4.x fixed this issue for me.